# Unable to read textfile with special characters from a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to read a textfile name with special characters(Ex: Student_*_Details.txt) from a directory. When I try to read them it says it has illegal characters in the path as the textfile name has these special characters and unable to read the file.

Code:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"\\NKR1009FHN\Student_*_Details.txt"))
```

I' have used the below set of codes to remove the illegal characters from the filename. But in the streamReader if fails as the special characters are getting replaced and unable to find the file since the actual filename got changed due to the below method used.

```
private static string GetValidFileName(string fileName) 
{
    String ret = Regex.Replace(fileName.Trim(), "[^A-Za-z0-9_. ]+", "")
    return ret.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
}
```

Is there any workaround to get this fixed?

Really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: have you tried using @ before the path?

Comment: Filenames with `*` are not allowed on Windows, are you sure the file contains that character?

Comment: @DanieleSartori - Yes, I have tried.

Comment: @DavidG - Filenames has lot of special characters is which makes me murky.

Comment: NTFS should not **allow** such a name. If you somehow have such a name either, something went horribly wrong during transmission. Or there is something you are not telling us.

Comment: How did you managed to save a file with that name? Can you change the name of the file or it has to be named like that?

Comment: Is the file called exactly "Student\_*\_Details.txt" or is it "Student\_<something>\_Details.txt"

Comment: @Samon - `Student_*_Details.txt` this is the exact name of the file.

Comment: I see two possibilities here: either this share is also mounted on a linux machine which produces these files, or it only _looks_ like a normal asterisk at first or second sight but is instead either an "Arabic five-pointed star" `٭` or a "combining asterisk above", char 20f0. Select the file for renaming, copy the file name into a hex editor, e.g. PSPad and look at the value of the "asterisk".

Comment: It is possible to create files with odd characters in them, including asterisk, but it only works for certain commands and those characters need escaping. For example `foo"*"bar.txt`